# React build prevent to remove unused images

Tags: reactjs, build, bundle

I have a React project created with CRA and yarn. I have some images in my assets folder that aren't being used. When I run yarn build and check the build folder I noticed that those images disaperead. I understand that this is for optimization, but I will need those images available.

How can I prevent those images being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are a few images that I didn't want to be deleted in the build process I move them to the `public/` folder.

Comment: this is not a valid question